# Authentication failure with Flask-Migrate and SQLAlchemy 2.0

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

After upgrading my flask application from SQLAlchemy 1.4.46 to 2.0.1 I'm seeing that I get a password authentication failed error during `flask db upgrade` (Flask-Migrate).  I'm able to connect fine running flask normally.  DB upgrades were working fine before the SQLAlchemy upgrade, and they work fine if I downgrade back to 1.4.46.

Has anything changed?  I'm providing the same `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL` is constructed with:

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{PG_USER}:{PG_PASSWORD}@{PG_HOST}:5432/{PG_DB}?{urlencode(LIBPQ_PARAMS)}"
```

and becomes

```
postgresql+psycopg2://user:xxx@example.com:5432/exampledb?connect_timeout=10&keepalives=1&keepalives_idle=60&keepalives_interval=10&keepalives_count=5&sslmode=require
```

in the logs, I see:

```
PG-00000 LOG:  connection received: host=10.101.15.236 port=53150
PG-28P01 FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
PG-28P01 DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 18: "hostssl all             all             0.0.0.0/0               scram-sha-256"
```

```
  File "/home/so/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "example.com" (10.101.1.28), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
```

Comment: Works for me on SQLA 2.0 and 2.0.1, although I didn't add the options after "?". Note that 2.0 includes a change to obscure the password in the string representation of the engine or its url. How are you constructing the engine & url in your migration script?

Comment: Note also that if I create a pure psycopg2 connection (`conn.psycopg2.connect(...)`) then the password is also obscured: `conn.dsn` -> `'user=sotest password=xxx dbname=test host=localhost'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release 4.0.4 of Flask-Migrate addresses this issue. Please upgrade.

The issue was caused by a backwards incompatible change in SQLAlchemy that masks the database password when obtaining the database URL.

Bug report: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-migrate/issues/505

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue in release 4.0.4.

Comment: Did you regenerate your migration repository? The issue is in the env.py file that is in your migrations folder. An upgrade alone is not going to refresh this file.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue in Flask-Migrate at this time:

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/505